# MatLAB keeps asking for activation

Tags: matlab

I'm having the exact problem this fellow is having in this thread:
[Matlab doesn't launch, keeps asking for activation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171348/matlab-doesnt-launch-keeps-asking-for-activation)

I've installed matlab successfully. However, I'm having trouble activating the software. What will happen is I'll type in

```
cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin
sudo ./matlab
```

Then a screen will pop up, where I'll have to follow the activating procedure. First I chose online activation. After typing my login information and activation key, it says that matlab has been successfully activated.

I'll start matlab again, but now I have to walk through the whole activation process once again. This time I chose offline mode, where I have to download a license key and direct the program to its location. It says matlab has been successfully activated. When I start matlab once more, it walks me through the activation process again.

Has anyone encountered and conquered this broken record machine?

Thanks!