# MATLAB Installation - Activation

Tags: matlab

I have just installed MATLAB 2016 using a license.dat file. Everything goes fine and the installation ends. When I try to run it then every single time it asks me to activate it. By using `sudo` it says activation complete and then nothing happens. When I run it again then it asks for activation once more. What is happening?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/171348/matlab-doesnt-launch-keeps-asking-for-activation

Comment: @Rinzwind That is the question I saw at first and made me ask a new one as none of the answers are useful.

Comment: Next time add that to the question  ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind Noted :P