# MATLAB License checkout failed in 16.04

Tags: matlab

As I tried to run MATLAB on my laptop, following results appear:

```
$ sudo -E matlab
[sudo] password for manish: 
License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -15
MATLAB is unable to connect to the license server. 
Check that the license manager has been started, and that the MATLAB client machine can communicate
with the license server.

Troubleshoot this issue by visiting: 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2014a/15

Diagnostic Information:
Feature: MATLAB 
License path: /home/manish/.matlab/R2014a_licenses:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/licenses/license.dat:/usr/local/MATLAB
/R2014a/licenses/network.lic 
Licensing error: -15,570. System Error: 115
```

PLEASE HELP ME!!!

Comment: Have you followed the suggestion in the output and troubleshooted the issue here: http://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2014a/15

Comment: I tried and the main thing is that the IP that's on network.lic is not responding... Is there any way to change that IP?

Comment: Have you tried the solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171348/matlab-doesnt-launch-keeps-asking-for-activation?rq=1)?